# Change image src for product "showoff"

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, src

I have a script which has a big image and three small images, now when one of the small images is clicked, I would like the big image to change into that image. I know this can be done by changing the image src I just dont know how, and then also I was thinking if this would be a good idea, considering the small images is another size than the big image, so maybe it would be best to just use the small images as buttons, and then only have the big image change to the bigger version of the small image the customer has clicked on.

My code(html):

```
<div class="poductoneimg">
                <img src="IphonePic1.jpg" alt="iPhone" style="height: 300px; width: 200px">
            </div>

            <div class="imgonethumbnail">
                <img src="IphonePic1.jpg" alt="iPhone" style="height: 70px; width: 40px">
            </div>

            <div class="imgtwothumbnail">
                <img src="IphonePic2.jpg" alt="iPhone" style="height: 70px; width: 40px">
            </div>

            <div class="imgthreethumbnail">
                <img src="IphonePic3.jpg" alt="iPhone" style="height: 70px; width: 40px">
            </div>
```

My code(css):

```
.productoneimg{
    position: absolute;
    top: 250px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -400px;
}

.imgonethumbnail{
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -380px;
    top: 580px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.imgtwothumbnail{
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -325px;
    top: 580px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.imgthreethumbnail{
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -270px;
    top: 580px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="poductoneimg">
                <img id="main" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="iPhone" style="height: 300px; width: 200px">
            </div>

            <div class="imgonethumbnail">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="iPhone" style="height: 70px; width: 40px"  onclick="changeimg(this.src)" >
            </div>

            <div class="imgtwothumbnail">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/250x150" alt="iPhone" style="height: 70px; width: 40px" onclick="changeimg(this.src)">
            </div>

            <div class="imgthreethumbnail">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/350x250" alt="iPhone" style="height: 70px; width: 40px" onclick="changeimg(this.src)">
            </div>
```

JS:

```
function changeimg(src) {
    document.getElementById('main').src=src;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/a3xhfc17/1/

Answer (score 0):

hope this helps

```
<div class="poductoneimg">
            <img src="IphonePic1.jpg" class='mainimg' alt="iPhone" style="height: 300px; width: 200px">
        </div>

        <div class="imgthumbnail">
            <img src="IphonePic1.jpg" alt="iPhone" style="height: 70px; width: 40px">
        </div>

        <div class="imgthumbnail">
            <img src="IphonePic2.jpg" alt="iPhone" style="height: 70px; width: 40px">
        </div>

        <div class="imgthumbnail">
            <img src="IphonePic3.jpg" alt="iPhone" style="height: 70px; width: 40px">
        </div>

$( ".imgthumbnail" ).click(function() {
  $('.mainimg').attr('src',$(this).attr('src'))
 });
```